# Adding a .sty file to the appropriate directory?

Tags: packages, installing

I am using emacs on Ubuntu 10.10.

I was trying to add `doublespace.sty` to my packages.

To figure out what directory to put the doublespace.sty in I did a search on my computer for `amsmath.sty`, since I know that package works, and found the directory it was in, which was a subdirectory of `/usr/share/texmf-texlive`. Since there are a bunch of `.sty` files in that directory, I decided to put `doublespace.sty` in `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/latex/base` . Then I ran `texhash` on that directory. But for some reason it is telling me it can't find `doublespace.sty` when I do `/usepackage{doublespace}`.

Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Don't use  `doublespace.sty`. It is an old package that has been replaced by [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace), which should be part of any TeX distribution.

Comment: Furthermore, you should never install packages into the main `texlive` directory, but use a local directory specifically for local additions.  See [Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/2693) for a general answer of how to install packages (but I repeat, don't install `doublespace`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `doublespace.sty`. It is an old package that has been replaced by [`setspace`](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace), which should be part of any TeX distribution (so you shouldn't need to install your own copy of it).

Furthermore, you should never install packages into the main texlive directory, but use a local directory specifically for local additions. [See Where do I place my own .sty files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/2693) for a general answer of how to install packages (but I repeat, don't install `doublespace`.)